# Android - Put object each others on Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I need to put a TextView on top of a Button in a RelativeLayout, so i put the TextView before the Button, but it doesn't work

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="20pt"
                android:layout_height="22pt"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_marginTop="4pt"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_numbers"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1" />
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/peso_but"
                android:layout_width="100pt"
                android:layout_height="20pt"
                android:layout_marginStart="17pt"
                android:layout_marginTop="5pt"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                android:backgroundTint="#3399ff"
                android:fontFamily="@font/fira_sans_semibold"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="#f5f5f5"
                android:textSize="8pt" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As I know, putting one object before another should work, but it doesn't

[image: I want something like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this you need to use **FrameLayout** for overlap views each other

```
   <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/peso_but"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#888"
        android:backgroundTint="#3399ff"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="#f5f5f5"
        android:textSize="8pt" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
         android:gravity="center"
        android:elevation="100dp"
        android:text="1" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `TextView` to overlap a `Button` replace your RelativeLayout with FrameLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Line in TextView

```
android:layout_abov="@+id/peso_but"
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your button

```
android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
```